# How Do I Display Document ID Using Meteor Spacebars?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, spacebars

I am new to Meteor, and I have an app that outputs data into rows of a table, I want to have a column for the ObjectID just for testing purposes, and I will disable this in production, but my handlebars template does not seem to output the _id at all.  any ideas are appreciated!
Here is my template:

```
<template name="Fillup">
   {{#each FillupArr}}
        <tr class="fillup row">
            <td> <div class="btnEdit">edit</div> <div class="btnSave" >save</div></td>
            <td class="">{{Fillup_id.toHexString}}</td>
            <td class="dateResult">{{Date}}</td>
            <td class="mpg">{{MPG}}</td>
            <td class="tripResult">{{Trip}}</td>
            <td class="ppg">{{PPG}}</td>
            <td class="ppm">{{PPM}}</td>
            <td class="galResult">{{Gal}}</td>
            <td class="priceResult">{{Price}}</td>
            <td class="stationResult">{{Station}}</td>
            <td> <div class="btnRemove">remove</div> <div class="btnCancel">cancel</div></td>
        </tr>
   {{/each}}
</template>
```

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out, you dont need to incude the collection name in the handlebars template so it changed from:

```
 <td class="">{{Fillup_id.toHexString}}</td>
```

to

```
 <td class="">{{_id}}</td>
```

and now it works!